# Styling a chamfer / scooped rectangle with a border

Tags: css

Trying to create a chamfer (aka scooped) style rectangle using CSS. Got it working for the most part. It's even responsive. However, I have a border element and on some screens, not all, it divided the rectangle (div) into two halves or even four quadrants. I know by default, this type of rectangle is difficult to create using CSS exclusively, but maybe someone knows why this is happening on some screen and what might be the fix.

**My code:**

```css
.div-chamfer {
  background: #674000;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, #674000 0) top left, linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 5px, #674000 0) top right, linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 5px, #674000 0) bottom right, linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 5px, #674000 0) bottom left;
  background-repeat: repeat, repeat, repeat, repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, rgb(103, 64, 0) 0px), linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 5px, rgb(103, 64, 0) 0px), linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 5px, rgb(103, 64, 0) 0px), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 5px, rgb(103, 64, 0) 0px);
  background-size: auto, auto, auto, auto;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, rgba(217, 191, 91, 0) 7px, #674000 8px), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, rgba(217, 191, 91, 0) 7px, #674000 8px), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, rgba(217, 191, 91, 0) 7px, #674000 8px), radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, rgba(217, 191, 91, 0) 7px, #674000 8px);
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #DCBD64;
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  height: 64px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-chamfer">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: what are screens affected? What's the wrong behavior? Could you provide a screenshot to illustrate this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: I'm trying the background size 51% idea, but haven't tested enough to really report back a positive or negative.

Answer (score 2):

Your background comes in from the edges to the center, it looks like sometimes sub-pixel rendering is causing it to jump back one pixel, you can fix that by over stretching your background just slightly to cause an overlap.

```
background-size: 51% 51%;
```

FYI: you can test that by setting a random width on your chamfer, notice that every uneven number will cause the line, since the engine can't divide a pixel in half to display what you're intending.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the background to show through, you can use a repeating area made with a radial gradient, which have a hole in the middle. The hole is moved to the corners by moving the area with background position. Cover the holes you don't need with another linear gradient that touches the sides, but not the corners.

```css
body {
  background: silver;
}

.div-chamfer {
  background:
    radial-gradient(closest-corner at center, #674000 85%, transparent 85%) center no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, transparent 7px, #674000 8px) -50% -50%/50% 50%;
  border: 1px solid #DCBD64;
  width: 75%;
  height: 64px;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-chamfer">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This solves the issue but at the cost of having to set the colour of the circles to match the background each time. This is a more suitable solution if the intention is to keep it white regardless of background colour.

Comment: Yea, I should have mentioned I want the scoops to show through. Be transparent. I’ve seen a lot of examples using background colors for the scoops, but that won’t work well in this instance.